# WooCommerce Export HTML Table to Excel

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello i have this table in the WooCommerce Dashboard
[image]

I want to add Export to Excel Button to export the HTML Table to Excel

But the problem is how can i include a javascript file in the WooCommerce->Report in dashboard

> /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-reports&tab=reports

I have added the below code in my `functions.php` file:

```
wp_register_script( 'zumra-reports', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/export-to-excel.js', array('jquery'), false, true );


if ( is_page('wc-reports') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'zumra-reports' );
}
```

but when i put any javascript it doesn't show in the WooCoomerce tab in dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code:

```
wp_register_script( 'zumra-reports', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/export-to-excel.js', array('jquery'), false, true );


if ( is_admin() && isset( $_GET['page'] ) && 'wc-reports' === $_GET['page'] ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'zumra-reports' );
}
```

It will add your script only on the WooCommerce Report page.